# How to use Sublime Text with the built-in Apple spellchecker

Tags: macos, spellcheck, sublimetext

Question in title. Is it possible at all with Sublime Text 3?
Now I can download different spellcheck packages or use the built-in ST spellchecker. However, I would like to use the Mac OS spellchecker as it does a great job in auto-correction and auto-detection of language.

I'm on the last Mountain Lion with Sublime Text 3.

**Edit**:
I found a plug-in that interfaces with the Apple Spellchecker. It's called [CheckBounce](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CheckBounce). Unfortunately it's broken with the current version of Sublime Text. So any alternatives are still welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime Text is tried to be cross-platform and as there is no built-in auto-correction functionality in other platforms, so if I was the programmer, I wouldn't relay on a feature present only in one of my target platforms and would implement the feature built-in my program to be portable to other platforms.
I love that feature of OS X too, but unfortunately I don't think if that would be possible in your case. :)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. It sounds like a logical explanation. I just thought maybe a plug-in or hidden setting would exist.

Answer (score 3):

Old post, but by now a plugin exists that interfaces with OS X's built-in spell checker.
See
https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=11692.
Haven't tried it myself yet, but will now!

Comment: In the edit part of my question (from nov 2013) I already refer to Checkbounce, but as I mention it's broken as of build 3049.